# No content being displayed using fixture adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to ember and am trying to display the title of some posts that I have using a fixture but for some reason none of the data gets displayed. When I added the handlebars script tag to my html file nothing is displayed at all.

I have a post model

```
Blog.Post = DS.Model.extend({
 title: DS.attr('string'),
 link: DS.attr('string')
});

Blog.Post.FIXTURES = [
{
 id: 0,
 title: 'first post',
link: 'www.google.com'
},
{
 id: 1,
 title: 'second post',
 link: 'www.reddit.com'
},
{
 id: 2,
 title: 'third post',
 link: 'www.wikipedia.com'
}
];
```

In my application.js

```
Blog.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

and in my router

```
Blog.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
  return this.store.find('post');
 }
});
```

and in my index.html file

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">

<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>
      {{title}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

</script>
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an application template, which is the root of your application.  Additionally your route is named Posts, plural, yet your template is named `post`, singular.

Additionally I don't see a router and `posts` resource in said router.  Here you'll see I've made them all plural.

```
Blog.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts');
});


Blog.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
  <h3>Post</h3>
  <ul>
    {{#each}}
      <li>
        {{title}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/501/edit

Comment: Thank you I didn't add the complete code for the files but i was able to figure out the problem after reading your comments. I was never looking at the actual posts route...duh. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to kingpin, your application template should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">

<div>
 {{outlet}}
</div>

</script>
```

Ember will automatically use the template without a "data-template-name" as the application template. The {{outlet}} will render your posts template when you are on the posts route.